# Installing UBUNTU 18.04 beside WIN 10 with inten core i5, 7th gen

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

Anyone who FOR SURE know how to install UBUNTU(ANY) on my brand new Lenovo idepad 330 with intel core i5, 7th gen?
Please reply! I am going crazy over this!
My 10 year old Acer could take 16.04 LTS without problems, but not 18.04 LTS.
Please help!

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). I advice you write your *specific problems*. Include as many details as you can. As it stands now you have some problem, but you do not tell us what the problem is. This question, as it stands, will probably be closed as *unclear*. There's no problem running Ubuntu on Intel CPU's, so that's a red herring.

Comment: After you have doen this:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi  Then tell us specific error or issue you have. Make sure Windows fast start up is off, and use Windows tools to shrink NTFS partition & reboot so it can run chkdsk before installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all. I bought my ideapad 330  15IKB i5 8225U 2weeks ago, and I use W10 10 and ubuntu 18.04. not problem at all.

But just one thing to remind: your lenovo motherboard tend to choose windows instead of ubuntu. You should either select "legacy first" if you already have a hard disk of Ubuntu, or reinstall it to choose "install ubuntu alongside windows".

Last but not least, if your windows updates, or lenovo asks you to upgrade your bios, it probably will go back to windows boot which means, you have to manually change it back. But in general, not problem at all.

Comment: Wow. Wonderful, someone answering and understanding my problem.
The thing is, for me now, what is "legacy first" and how do I "install ubuntu alongside windows".
I must admit I AM NOT A COMPUTERWIZARD!!!!
So if possible please give step by step instructions.
I have used ubuntu for almost 20 years and it seems to be more and more complicated to INSTALL! As of now the purchase of this Lenovo feels like a huge mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Each model is different, but anyway, I am assuming that your new laptop is very similar to mine, that Win 10 is pre-installed and you want to install ubuntu alongside windows:

1. From your OS (say your Win 10) go to ubuntu official website to download ubuntu 18.04 iso file, after the download, also download bootable usb creator, for instance **Rufus**.
2. Prepare a 8GB clean USB and follow instruction for creating bootable USB for ubuntu installation.
3. After that, without removing USB, reboot your PC and constantly press **F2** to enter your **BIOS**, their, go to BIOS menu, select your USB as first bootloader (at your USB disk option you have to press **F6** to move this option to the top), save and exit and should should be fine to enter Ubuntu installing menu.
4. Once entered the ubuntu installation menu, select install ubuntu, and follow the instruction until you are asked to select what to do with your disk, I remember basically there are three options (*1. Install Ubuntu alongside Windows; 2. Format disk and install Ubuntu and 3. Do something else*).

5.1 If you don't know what to do and afraid to mess up with your computer and Win 10, just select the first one, and normally ubuntu will split your disk into two partitions, half for windows and half for ubuntu. Continue and install. All good.

5.2 If you want to have a smaller/bigger partition for Ubuntu/Win 10, then at step *4*, you should select "*try ubuntu without installing*". Once entered the Ubuntu trial OS, use gparted to shrink your Win 10 partition to ideal capacity, apply and reboot (back to step *3*)

5.2.1 Same as previously described at *5.1*, this time choose do something else. And assign the unallocated partition as your root (/), whether assigning swap is completely up to you. And follow the instruction and you should be able to install ubuntu without any problem.

I attach a video of instruction, may it helps. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5QyjHIYwTQ&t=218s

Remember to mark "problem solved (tick)" if your think this is helpful.